# Is there any standard URL for detecting presence of captive portal?

Tags: network-programming, captivenetwork, captiveportal

I am writing an application wherein I would like to check if the user is connected to the Access Point, but network access is not permitted(due to presence of captive portal).

The following URL is a test server from Microsoft, and if everything is successful then it returns HTTP 200 , with content as "Microsoft Connect Test"
http://www.msftconnecttest.com/connecttest.txt

To return the status back to the user, I would like to double check with one more test server, which returns some content in the HTML response.

There is one test server from Google as "http://connectivitycheck.gstatic.com/generate_204", but this gives empty HTML response.

Couple of servers are available from Mozilla and Apple, but all returns "SUCCESS" in HTML response.

Why I dont prefer any test server which returns merely "SUCCESS" in HTML body is because, it doesnt allow me to test the scenario of content tamper attack.

pl reply if you know any other standard server to test captive portals...

~Ashish

Answer (score 6):

I know this is a really old question, but I might have some extra info for anyone else landing here.

Although the Google generate_204 link appears to return nothing, it actually returns a 204 status. If there is a captive portal in play on your connection, you will not get a 204 back.

We use this in our applications to detect captive portals and it works well. We have a 'Hello' endpoint on our APIs that returns a 204.

Answer (score 3):

To know that you are connected to a captive portal on which you have not been authenticated yet, you can use any https (http over SSL/TLS) URL since the captive portal will not be able to complete a correct handshake because it does not have the secret key associated to a valid X.509 certificate that has been signed by a known root CA or an intermediate one. Moreover, this protects you against content tamper attack.

Once authenticated to the captive portal, you can check that the captive portal makes use of a transparent proxy using any http URL with the HTTP/1.0 protocol, since most captive portals look for the « Host: » header (that appeared in HTTP/1.1) to be able to get the real host you want to connect to.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but actually I am looking for a URL which generates some text in response to HTTP request. For example http://www.msftconnecttest.com/connecttest.txt  generates "Microsoft Connect Test" in response.  The returned text helps me to validate if there is any content tamper attack is going on or not on the connected Access Point.

Comment: I got another HTTP server which is used by Debian Linux http://network-test.debian.org/nm" and it generates a text "NetworkManager is online" in return. But I am not sure how reliable this test server will be, since my application users are spreaded across the world and easily thousands of requests can be expected simultaneously within a second.

Comment: To avoid content tamper attack, why do not you simply use https instead of http?

Comment: Https traffic is usually blocked by captive portals. And I want some http trafiic which generates response other than success . Success http response is being generated by many servers lile apple and mozilla. But these servers cant be used because success word is very common and can be present easily in content tamperd page or in custom html page which AP can retun to user to authenticate

Comment: Since « https traffic is usually blocked by captive portals », this seems to be a good way to detect the presence of a captive portal. You ask for « an URL for detecting presence of a captive portal », so why not using https?